# Argon - Decryption Issues of Vuforia License

Tags: vuforia, argon

I am using the Argon 3 web browser with Vuforia's image tracking.  I've taken the license key of my Vuforia application and encrypted it with the GPG Keychain.  I've included relevant snippets of my `index.html` and `app.js` files here.

Whenever I load up my application, I get the error:

```
Vuforia: could not decrypt vuforia license JSON
```

Running it in the debugger shows:

```
Unexpected token VSyntaxError: Unexpected token V
   at Object.parse(native)
...
```

**index.html**

```
<script id="license" type="text/plain">-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Comment: GPGTools - https://gpgtools.org
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=qaTl
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
// Tell Argon that we need Vuforia for image tracking
Argon.immersiveContext.setRequiredCapabilities('Vuforia');


var encryptedData = document.getElementById("license").text;

// initialize Vuforia with our license key
Argon.Vuforia.initialize({
    encryptedLicenseData: encryptedData,
    startCamera: true,
}).then(function(api)
    { 
        // load, activate, and use our dataSet 
        api.loadDataSetFromURL('./auburn_map.xml').then(function (dataSet)
        { 
            dataSet.activate(); 
            setupStreetCar(dataSet.trackables.streetcar);
        }).then(api.startObjectTracker)
          .then(api.hintMaxSimultaneousImageTargets.bind(api, 2));
    });
```

I am unsure of what to do from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I encrypted the JSON file using the GPG keychain.  I created a new keypair with the email "secure@argonjs.io", went to my JSON file, highlighted the text, selected that I wanted to encrypt and did NOT sign or encrypt with password.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you encrypt this JSON file?  You need to encrypt with the secure@argonjs.io public key, and do not sign it or encrypt with a password.

Comment: Hm, I did do exactly as you said though I might have been incorrect on a step, perhaps?  I've edited my original post with pictures describing what I did.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I see the problem:  you created a new key for secure@argonjs.io, which is not what you want (that creates a public/private key that you own).  You need to use "Lookup Key" to find the public key for secure@argonjs.io that we published, import it, and encrypt the file using it.

The idea is that Argon3 has the private key, and can decrypt JSON files encrypted with it's public key.

Comment: Thank you!  I did just as you said and it did seem to work.  Also, I realized that I had a "d'oh!" moment as my screenshot showed that I was trying to encrypt an XML instead of a JSON file.